# Jenkins Maven Builds using Multi Configurations

Tags: android, maven, configuration, android-emulator, jenkins

I am setting up a CI server at work (first time for everything) and got a question.

So, My Maven job works great, building and performing my tests.

However I wish to use Multi Configuration to create multiple emulators to run my tests through.

Can someone tell me definitively if I can do this or not? The documentation here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin seems contradictory with some comments I have seen.

I can't be the only person who wants to use Maven and Jenkins in this way so is there any work arounds? 
In the mean time I will be creating many jobs and staggering their nightly builds for each emulator, However this feels very sloppy and I can see it becoming unmanageable very soon.

Comment: did you have a look at the multi configuration section in that wiki? Why exactly won't this work? Have you tried?

Comment: when i create a multi configuration job it does not give me the maven build options which i need.

Comment: The Android Emulator Plugin wiki page doesn't mention Maven at all — what's contradictory? While not as simple as using the Maven job type, can't you just call Maven manually in a multi-configuration job?

Comment: "can't you just call Maven manually in a multi-configuration job? " yeah probably this is the crux of my question.... how?

Comment: Add an "Execute Shell" build step where you run `mvn whatever`.

Comment: cheers that sorted me out!

Answer (score 0):

The Multi-Configuration Job runs like any other job,
though it may have some limited support for plugins.

If having problem with the Maven Plugin, run it via an "Execute Shell" block
before you actually start the build - as mentioned by [*Christopher*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234938/christopher).

Note it will run the exact same script for all configurations,
except for the different parameters each will have.